# Get Azure active directory user group objectId in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Hi I am trying to deploy the resource using ARM template of type "Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators"
below is the template

```
{
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/administrators",
          "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
          "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServerName'), '/ActiveDirectory')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServerName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
            "login": "[parameters('activeDirectoryUserGroupName')]",
            "sid": "",
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"
          }
        }
```

I am passing the active directory user group name as parameter, "sid" is the objectId of that active directory group. So is there any way to fetch the objectId in ARM template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have no way to get the Azure AD group object id in Azure ARM template. Because the Azure AD group is Azure AD resource. It is not Azure resource. But the ARM template is only used to manage Azure resources. For more details,  please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview)  and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview)

If the want to get the AD group object id, you can use Azure Powershell command `$groubId=(Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName <groupName>).Id`.